# Netbeans: Is it possible to convert a hand-coded GUI into one understood by Matisse?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, matisse

I'm starting development on an existing open source project that used a hand-coded GUI.  Is it possible to somehow import this into Matisse, so that I can edit this project's GUI in Matisse?  Or do I basically have to rebuild it from scratch in Matisse?

Cheers,
red.october

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is very hard to do ( dare I say impossible? ). There are so many style of coding, that I think it would be far faster to redesign everything using Matisse, than to get some half-decent code automatically generated.

If you designed your code somewhat efficiently, you should be able to make the transition to Matisse pretty painless.

Comment: I should make it clearer that this is an existing open source project developed by someone else.  I'm just going to do some work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a conversion. 
You could create smaller handcoded components (which has to be a bean) and add them to the GUI palette to create a new Matisse-based GUI.

For more info look [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the eclipse WindowBuilder tool, it works similarly to matisse, and reads real java code instead of form files..